# Passing ViewModel to Action using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Is it possible to pass viewmodel to controllers action method calling it using jQuery?
Currently in Action model is empty.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(MyModel model)
    {
        ProcessModel(model);

        return Json(new
        {
            Result = "result"
        });
    }
```

jQuery:

```
function Serve() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //Handle errors here...
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function (content) { alert('Cannot find resource'); },
            505: function (content) { alert('Status code: 505'); },
            500: function (content) { alert('Internal server error'); }
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);

        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: What are the properties in your ViewModel, and what data are you trying to pass?

Comment: yes it is possible, why don't you just try it

Comment: Where is your `data` parameter?

Comment: Right "data"! How do I pass instance of MyModel using: data: "", dataType : "" attribute pair?

Comment: serialize the form data >> http://api.jquery.com/serialize. The default MVC model binder handles mapping form values to strongly typed models. this works well as long as you ensure your form fields are either generated using strongly typed helpers or match the named model properties @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PropertyName)

Comment: Mark, it was enough to add "data: $("form").serialize()" don't you want to put it as answer here and ill accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialize the form data using [api.jquery.com/serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and the default MVC model binder will handle mapping form values to strongly typed models.

This works well as long as you ensure your form fields are either generated using strongly typed HTML helpers or match the named model properties:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PropertyName)
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="Model.PropertyName" />
```